# Can't find the value of three keys required to be used within parameters in requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I've created a script using requests module to scrape different addresses revealed upon clicking on a box like [container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1y03w.jpg) on a map located in a [webpage](https://www.bcassessment.ca//Property/Info/QTAwMDAwMDAyRg==). To get the results, it is necessary to issue a get requests along with appropriate parameters.

In the parameters, there are three things that I wish not to hardcode. The value of `x`,`y` and `wkid` within `geometry`. Currrently they are hardcoded.

I've tried with (the script runs if you copy the updated token from that site):

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.bcassessment.ca//Property/Info/QTAwMDAwMDAyRg=='
link = 'https://arcgis.bcassessment.ca/ext_wa/rest/services/DCX/AFP_20210325/MapServer/0/query'

params = {
    'token': 'NHkz-ovnHMz14v7omW68nK6cYpfv3NYcbxelXdxg6tlVj7sGSpGdR44TILwVDIqMK2hWKPv5keKrbs25dIYJGQ..',
    'f': 'json',
    'where': '',
    'returnGeometry': 'true',
    'geometry': "{'x':'-13715482.217555167','y':'6320767.279841547','spatialReference':{'wkid':102100}}",
    'geometryType': 'esriGeometryPoint',
    'inSR': '102100',
    'outFields': 'AFP_OID,UNIT_NUMBER,TOTAL_ASSESSED,ROLL,AREA_EVBC,JUR,TOTAL_LAND,TOTAL_BUILDING,ADDRESS,DESCRIPTION,STREET_NUMBER,STREET_NAME,OID_EVBC,SHORT_ADDRESS,IS_STRATA,FARM_FLAG,UTILITY_FLAG,MAJ_INDUSTRY_FLAG,MANAGED_FOREST_FLAG',
    'orderByFields': 'STREET_NAME,STREET_NUMBER,UNIT_NUMBER,SHORT_ADDRESS',
    'outSR': '102100'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    s.headers['Referer'] = 'https://www.bcassessment.ca/'
    res = s.get(link,params=params)
    for item in res.json()['features']:
        print(item['attributes']['ADDRESS'])
```

Output:

```
1-1980 SASAMAT ST VANCOUVER
2-1980 SASAMAT ST VANCOUVER
3-1980 SASAMAT ST VANCOUVER
4-1980 SASAMAT ST VANCOUVER
5-1980 SASAMAT ST VANCOUVER
6-1980 SASAMAT ST VANCOUVER
7-1980 SASAMAT ST VANCOUVER
```

***How can I not hardcode the value of `x`,`y` and `wkid` within `params` and still get the same results?***

Comment: What is the purpose of the values x, y and wkid?

Comment: I don't know the purpose of those values but I do know that you need to use their values in the params to get the result.

Comment: Without understanding how the variables are used, how do you expect anyone else to assist you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get those parameters `x`, `y`, `token` in page by `Beautifulsoup` and `regex`.

By the source of Javascript(`init.js`) in the page, the parameter `wkid` would only be `4326` or `102100`(mostly). So just send request for each one of them.

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page_url = "https://www.bcassessment.ca//Property/Info/QTAwMDAwMDAyRg=="
# page_url = "https://www.bcassessment.ca//Property/Info/QTAwMDAwMDAxSw=="
query_url = "https://arcgis.bcassessment.ca/ext_wa/rest/services/DCX/AFP_20210325/MapServer/0/query"
regex_xy = r"mapInitialCenter = \[(.*)\]"
regex_token = r"gistoken = \'(.*?)\';"
headers = {
    'Referer': 'https://www.bcassessment.ca/',
}
params = {
    'geometryType': 'esriGeometryPoint',
    'outFields': 'AFP_OID,UNIT_NUMBER,TOTAL_ASSESSED,ROLL,AREA_EVBC,JUR,TOTAL_LAND,TOTAL_BUILDING,ADDRESS,DESCRIPTION,STREET_NUMBER,STREET_NAME,OID_EVBC,SHORT_ADDRESS,IS_STRATA,FARM_FLAG,UTILITY_FLAG,MAJ_INDUSTRY_FLAG,MANAGED_FOREST_FLAG',
    'orderByFields': 'STREET_NAME,STREET_NUMBER,UNIT_NUMBER,SHORT_ADDRESS',
    'f': 'json'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = headers
    resp = s.get(page_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "lxml")

    # get token string in page
    token_ = soup.select_one("#Property > div:nth-child(7) > script:nth-child(1)").string 
    token = re.search(regex_token, token_).group(1)

    # get x, y parameter in page
    geometry_tag = soup.select_one("body > div:nth-child(1) > script:nth-child(3)")
    x, y = re.search(regex_xy, geometry_tag.string).group(1).split(", ")
    result = []
    params['token'] = token
    for wkid in ['4326', '102100']:
        params['geometry'] = '{"x":' + x +',"y":'+ y +',"spatialReference":{"wkid":' + wkid +'}}'
        resp = s.get(query_url, params=params)
        for item in resp.json()['features']:
            result.append(item['attributes']['ADDRESS'])
    
print(*result, sep="\n")
```

Gave me:

```
1-1980 SASAMAT ST VANCOUVER
2-1980 SASAMAT ST VANCOUVER
3-1980 SASAMAT ST VANCOUVER
4-1980 SASAMAT ST VANCOUVER
5-1980 SASAMAT ST VANCOUVER
6-1980 SASAMAT ST VANCOUVER
7-1980 SASAMAT ST VANCOUVER
```

And [this page](https://www.bcassessment.ca//Property/Info/QTAwMDAwMDAxSw==) gave me:

```
1505 TOLMIE ST VANCOUVER
```

Comment: It appears that your solution is working perfectly. I'll try with few more property links later. That `wkid` thing is still a mystery, though. Thanks a trillion for your epic solution.

Comment: @MITHU `wkid` is assigned in `init.js`, if you try to search `wkid` string in `init.js`, you will know how it get assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find out where original web page them.

After high-level investigation it looks like following request contains GIS data:
https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer?f=json

But if you need just following output from that page:

```
1-1980 SASAMAT ST VANCOUVER
2-1980 SASAMAT ST VANCOUVER
3-1980 SASAMAT ST VANCOUVER
4-1980 SASAMAT ST VANCOUVER
5-1980 SASAMAT ST VANCOUVER
6-1980 SASAMAT ST VANCOUVER
7-1980 SASAMAT ST VANCOUVER
```

Maybe it is better to parse this URL: https://www.bcassessment.ca/Property/Nearby

Comment: Thanks for your answer @wowkin2. The thing is this [request](https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer?f=json) doesn't contain the value of `x` and `y`. Moreover, that very request contains the same stuff no matter whatever property link I use. Here is another [property link](https://www.bcassessment.ca//Property/Info/QTAwMDAwMDAxSw==) for your consideration. Btw, the response that I get from this link `/Property/Nearby` doesn't contain the same information as we see in that map. Thanks again.